# How to use a function in Android that was only available earlier API Levels?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

Below is my function, you can see that `getAllVisitedUrls` and `BookmarkColumns` are highlighted in red as being unsupported. This is because they are [unsupported in Android 6.0 Marshmallow](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser).

Anyhow, I want to continue using these functions for API Levels < M (23). How can I do that and not get this error?

[image]

This is the function in text in case you want to edit it in text for the answer:

```
 private void getLastURL() {

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Cursor cursor = Browser.getAllVisitedUrls(getContentResolver());
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String urlVisited = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.URL));
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to directly code to those APIs will require you to set your `compileSdkVersion` to 22 or lower, whether for your whole project or for some library module in which you place this code.

You can also use reflection (e.g., `Class.forName()`) to try to get at this stuff.